# Creating a custom LiveCD 

Tags: iso-image, livecd

I am trying to build a custom live cd from a Fedora 14 or CentOS 6 install. I have tried the [process found on the Fedora Wiki](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/How_to_create_and_use_a_Live_CD). It's basically using the livecd-tools program and then using some kick start scripts to customize it. However each time I've done this, the ISO didn't work. The first time I got the following error:

> /etc/rc.d/rc.sysinit: line 405: /sbin/fsck: Input/output error
>
> **An error occurred during the file system check.
>   ** Dropping you to a shell; the system will reboot when you leave the shell.

This was with Fedora. The second time I did it with CentOS, it hung on the CentOS blue screen after clicking on the "Boot" option.

I've also tried the clonesys program and everytime I use that I get an error about not being about to mound the cdrom.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [Revisor](http://revisor.fedoraunity.org/)?  It's a GUI for creating Fedora live media.

You can install it from the official Fedora repostiory:

```
sudo yum install revisor
```

Comment: I've read about it but haven't tried it yet. My only concern with Revisor is, from what I read it makes a new ISO image out of the packages you pick. While that is good, I also want it to mimic my desktop settings, icons, etc. I want it just like my current running setup.

Comment: @Eric:  Revisor also supports configuring custom options via kickstart.